# Meaning of acceptor/donor splicing sites?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, splicing

What is the meaning of **acceptor** and **donor** in *acceptor site* and *donor site* expressions in the context of RNA splicing. Note that I know the biological meaning of these concepts. I am just intrigued by the terms **acceptor** and **donor**.

I just cannot seem to find the reason why one is called **acceptor** and other **donor**. What exactly is being accepted and donated? In addition, it would be nice to have a reference to the original work that used this terminology.